# Tab is not shown after tab's disabled and active property are set to true. Angularjs Tabs

Tags: angularjs, tabs

I am working w/ Angularjs.
i am using Tabs and accordion directives.
When tab's disabled and active properties are set to true, tab's content is not showing up.
Here is [my plunker snippet](http://plnkr.co/edit/zJBlDBw4NlhxvXOV5d7K?p=preview) that reproduces the issue. Click on PL item and click on Mode 1. The Mode tab will become active and but not shown.
I have a gut feeling it is due to ng-include but do not see why ...

**Index.html**

```
  <div ng-controller="LeftPaneCtrl">
      <tabset>          
                <tab ng-repeat="tab in leftPane.tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">
                     <div ng-include="tab.content"></div>
                </tab>
            </tabset>
            </div>
  </body>
```

**Modules.Html:**

```
<accordion close-others="true">    
    <accordion-group heading="{{module.displayName}}" ng-repeat="module in leftPane.modules">
        <div ng-repeat="mode in module.modes" >
            <a style="color: green" ng-click="leftPane.selectMode(module, mode)">{{mode.title}} </a>    
        </div>        
    </accordion-group>    
</accordion>
```

**Srcipt.js:**

```
function LeftPaneModel() {
    this.tabs = [
        { title: "Modules", content: "Modules.html", active: true},
        { title: "Modes", content: "Modes.html", disabled: true, active: false },
        { title: "Reports", content: "Reports.html", disabled: true, active: false }
    ];
    this.modulesTab = this.tabs[0];
    this.modesTab = this.tabs[1];
    this.reportsTab = this.tabs[2];
    this.modules = [];
    this.modules.push({displayName:'PL',modes:[{title:'Mode 1',id:'Mode1'},{title:'Mode 2',id:'Mode2'}]})
    this.selectMode = function(module, mode) {    
        var tab = this.modesTab;            
        tab.title = mode.title;                
        tab.active = true;
        tab.disabled = false;
    };
}
var emsApp = angular.module('EmsWeb', ['ui.bootstrap']);

emsApp.controller('LeftPaneCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

  $scope.leftPane = new LeftPaneModel();

}]);
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted as an issue w/ angular-ui team. They fixed the issue and should be in next release.
Here is the [link](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/642) to the thread.